# a percentage values in crystal report

Tags: charts, crystal-reports, report, percentage

I have values in database witch is a percentage values for example:

Per columns : 90,85,38,70,85

I select “Per” as the value to be shown in the bar chart 
But when I run my crystal report all my bar display as 100% 
It does not take the exact value of “Per”

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column values are whole numbers then you should probably create a formula to calculate the fraction. Then you should be able to display as a percentage. Eg. {table.fieldname} * .01